# tools.jar do JDK

Tags: java, jdk

Eu estou usando o `tools.jar` do JDK (mais especificamente o [Attach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html)) em uma aplicação, porém, de acordo com as minhas pesquisas o `tools.jar` não consegue ser executado em um ambiente JRE "por depender do JDK".

É isso mesmo ou existe alguma forma de compilar a aplicação com o `tools.jar` de dependência e rodar a aplicação em um ambiente JRE?

Comment: Tiago, se essa edição é uma resposta, você deve postar no campo abaixo e remover da pergunta.

Comment: @diegofm Feito, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido efetuando o load do `attach.dll` ao iniciar a aplicação.

```
System.load("path/attach.dll");
```